# Selenium sometimes returns a WebDriverException at different areas when in Gmail

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm writing an automated task that will get an authentication code from Gmail for another website.

Selenium does two things. First login to the website and get the prompt to enter the authentication code, and then opens a new tab and goes to Gmail to get that code.

For some reason at different parts of getting the code from Gmail (i.e. login, open mail, getText(), logout), it will sometimes return a:

```
WARNING: WebDriverException thrown by findElement(By.xpath: EnterXpathHere])
```

The thing is that it would only sometimes throw the error. There's a like 75% chance that it will return the exception. For that 25% it will finish the rest of the task

I tried editing the xpath and rewriting the process to get that code, but that exception still return no matter how different I try to make it.

Please tell me if I need to provide any additional info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably introducing `WebDriverWait` will resolve your issues. The usage as following:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("your xPath"))).click();
```

This will wait at least 10 seconds, until element will be clickable and only then clicks on it.

***Note:*** you have to do some imports:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
```

More information can be found in the documentation [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html).

Comment: Thanks. That did noticeably reduce the amount of thrown exceptions, but there's still one that keeps coming up that doesn't have to do with waiting for the element to be clickable, but visible instead. `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xPathGmail.authenticationMail)));` and it returns the same error.

Comment: Please show the code you have and tell which line throws an exception, and which exception

Comment: `xPathGmail.authenticationMail` it is not a valid xPath

Comment: Odd. XPath Helper does find it when typing the xpath. I'll try and write another one.

Comment: can you provide a link to website?

Comment: I've managed to fix the issue. I've added an additional visibility of element before the email and it stopped throwing the exception. Well unlike Steam, there's a tiny span where items in Gmail are not clickable even if they are visible. Thank you for your help.